# Application via Market and my own server. What about crash reports?

Tags: android, deployment

I'm not sure how this is going to work. Let's say I have android app and I will distribute it via Android market AND keep it on my server as well (same APK)

I have my own way of updating application (download APK and prompt user to install). I wonder if this application will be reporting crashes/ANR ot market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it must be downloaded from Google Play in order to get the benefit of crash reports.

Comment: I'm still not sure how. What if I didn't publish on market and install APK manually? Are you saying that any app will report crashes to Market?